# System Functions in postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql

How to List all system functions in postgresql in a short method?

Comment: please provide the code you have already tried and want to be shortened

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    (SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace WHERE oid = pp.pronamespace) AS schemaname,
    COALESCE((SELECT nspname||'.' FROM pg_namespace WHERE oid = pp.pronamespace AND nspname != 'public'), '')||proname AS full_name,
    proname, pg_get_function_arguments(pp.oid) AS proargs, prosrc, procost, prorows, prosecdef,
    pg_get_function_result(pp.oid) AS prorettype,
    (SELECT lanname FROM pg_language WHERE oid = pp.prolang) AS prolang,
    (CASE WHEN provolatile='v' THEN 'VOLATILE' WHEN provolatile='i' THEN 'IMMUTABLE' ELSE 'STABLE' END) AS volatility,
    obj_description(pp.oid, 'pg_proc') AS description
FROM pg_proc pp
WHERE (SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace WHERE oid = pp.pronamespace) = 'pg_catalog'
    AND NOT pp.proisagg AND NOT pp.proiswindow
ORDER BY proname, proargnames, proargtypes
```